# Optimal release angle for rubber-band powered catapult

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, elasticity

I'm building a rubber-band powered catapult, and wondering what the optimal release angle is (for maximum range). If velocity is held constant, it's obviously $\pi/4$, but with rubber bands, the release velocity increases with release angle, leading me to believe that the optimal angle would be greater than $\pi/4$.

Assuming that the rubber bands fully follow Hooke's law, and displacement used in Hooke's law is $R*(1-sin(\theta))$ (you can see why this happens with my type of catapult in this diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Sir.png), what is the optimal release angle for maximum range?

Also, what happens when one adds friction into the mix? Does it reduce the optimal release angle because at low displacements, friction might overpower the restoring force? If so, approximately by how much?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a theoretical interest in this problem, please show your own attempt to solve it. Officially we do not solve problems for you. If you have a practical interest in the outcome, why don't you do an experiment?

Comment: @sammygerbil oh, sorry! I hadn't gotten very far before getting stuck, but i'll put my efforts up. I am currently building the catapult, but was wondering about the theoretical underpinnings. Also, this isn't homework of any sort.

Comment: The tag is homework-and-EXERCISES. Any question asking for a calculation to be done is an EXERCISE. ... Yes,  please show your attempt and ask about what is preventing you from completing the calculation.

Comment: @sammygerbil srry, i'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal angle does not depend on how the projectile is accelerated since the trajectory is determined completely by the ballistics of free fall.  In the simplest case of no air friction the optimal angle is $\pi/4$ as you guessed.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't depend on how it is accelerated, but it does depend on the final release velocity, which increases if it gets accelerated for longer

Comment: then I misunderstood your question. sorry.  you need to find the functional dependence between the angle, the magnitude of the release velocity, and the direction of your release velocity.  Good luck.